# Is there a way to use jQuery .append on contenteditable text position?

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Like the title say's, Is there a way to use jQuery .append on contenteditable div, selected text position? I can find a lot for the contenteditable insert html at that position. But I need the jQuery .append function.

Cheers!

```js
var ffclickcount = 0;
  $('#fff').click(function(e) {
    ffclickcount = ffclickcount + 1;
    var newfff = '<br/><form> <textarea id="ItemNEW' + ffclickcount + '"></textarea> </form><br/>';
    $("#Ntext").append(newfff);
    
  });
  
  // IN MY OWN CODE I HAVE THIS ALSO INSIDE THE VAR NEWFFF BUT THAT GIVES A ERROR ON SO SNIPPET //
 // <script> var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("ItemNEW'+ffclickcount+'"), { mode: "text/html", theme: "eclipse", lineWrapping: true, styleActiveLine: true, matchBrackets: true, readOnly: false }); var charWidth = editor.defaultCharWidth(), basePadding = 4; editor.on("renderLine", function(cm, line, elt) { var off = CodeMirror.countColumn(line.text, null, cm.getOption("tabSize")) * charWidth; elt.style.textIndent = "-" + off + "px"; elt.style.paddingLeft = (basePadding + off) + "px"; }); editor.refresh(); </script>
```

```css
.SWItextar {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    min-height:50vh;
    margin-top:1vh;
    margin-bottom:1vh;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow-x: auto;
    outline:none;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="fff">click insert form</span>
<div name="text" id="Ntext" class="SWItextar" contenteditable="true" autofocus></div>
```

Comment: you just want to find a way to insert content into a div with contenteditable rule similar to principle `append`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated the question with a code example. @s.kuznetsov I want to find a way to use append on the text cursor position.

Comment: Up! Anybody... ?